# prove existence, uniqueness and non-negativity of the system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, mathematical-modeling, lipschitz-functions

I have an epidemic model with 9 compartments, where all epidemic parameters are non-negative.
\begin{equation} \label{model}
 \begin{split}
  &\frac{dS}{dt}  = \beta N   -\delta S-\phi \frac {SI}{N} \qquad\qquad [I=Is+Ia]\\
  &\frac{ dE}{dt} = \phi \frac {SI}{N}-(\delta +\psi+\rho+\mu)E\\
  &\frac{dQ}{dt}  = \mu E-(\alpha+\sigma+r+\delta ) Q\\
  &\frac{ dIs}{dt} = \psi E +\alpha Q-(\kappa+h+\delta)Is\\
  &\frac{dIa}{dt} = \rho E+\sigma Q-(m+l+\delta)Ia \\
  &\frac{dH}{dt} =  \kappa Is+l Ia+\nu Hm-(\epsilon +n+\delta) H\\
  &\frac{dHm}{dt}  = m Ia+h Is-(q+\delta+\eta+\nu)Hm \\
  &\frac{ dRc}{dt} = n H+p Ia+q Hm +rQ-\delta Rc\\
  &\frac{dD}{dt} = \epsilon H +\eta Hm
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

with the conditions,

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  &S(t)+E(t)+Q(t)+I_s(t)\\
  &+I_a(t)+H(t)+H_m(t)+R_c(t)+D(t)=N\\
  &S(0)+E(0)+Q(0)+I_s(0)+I_a(0)\\
  &+H(0)+H_m(0)+R_c(0)+D(0)=N_0
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
I have to prove a therem : The solution of each of the compartmental values $S, E, I_s, I_a, Q, Hm, H, R, D$ of system uniquely exists in $\scriptsize R_+^{9}$ and is non negative for given initial conditions at any time $t$. 
Problem are Establishing Lipschitz Continuity, Lipschitz constant as some ODE have non-linear terms.